# Acrobat SDK C# tutorial

Tags: c#, acrobat

Could you help me to start developing an pdf viewer,reader with aid of Acrobat SDK.
If you can give me a clear guidance(tutorial).

thank you
yohan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The developer centre at Adobe is obviously the first point to start with.

Go to: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html

Comment: I can't figure out where to navigate to the downloads: "Welcome to the 2021 release of the Acrobat SDK. The downloads are new and the documentation is rapidly evolving." Where are the links to the downloads?

Comment: It turns out it's not a public facing link, the [release notes](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/releasenotes.html) gives the instructions "To access the downloads: Go to https://developer.adobe.com/console/servicesandapis. Download the SDK"